# Very strange problem when trying to serve a model with mlflow

Tags: python, windows, mlflow

I'm trying to serve a model with mlflow, using the following command : `!mlflow models serve -m "models:/sklearn_housing_prices_model/1" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 8001`

But I have this message that I do not manage to understand, even if I tried and tried... :

```
:: [Info] ::  Mirror: https://www.python.org/ftp/python
created virtual environment CPython3.10.9.final.0-64 in 929ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\numer\.mlflow\envs\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\numer\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==23.3.2, setuptools==69.0.3, wheel==0.42.0
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator


Downloading artifacts:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Downloading artifacts: 100%|##########| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Downloading artifacts: 100%|##########| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
2024/01/19 17:15:23 INFO mlflow.models.flavor_backend_registry: Selected backend for flavor 'python_function'
2024/01/19 17:15:23 INFO mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Installing python 3.10.9 if it does not exist
2024/01/19 17:15:24 INFO mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Creating a new environment in C:\Users\numer\.mlflow\envs\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79 with C:\Users\numer\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.10.9\python.exe
2024/01/19 17:15:26 INFO mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Installing dependencies
2024/01/19 17:15:26 WARNING mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Failed to symlink model directory during dependency installation Copying instead. Exception: [WinError 1314] Le client ne dispose pas d’un privilège nécessaire: 'C:\\Users\\numer\\S4\\ML Ops\\mlruns\\280660009522813491\\09e1ab82c96d4e3599342218aa1bd0bd\\artifacts\\sklearn-model\\conda.yaml' -> 'C:\\Users\\numer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpgrt1wdna\\conda.yaml'
2024/01/19 17:15:35 WARNING mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Failed to symlink model directory during dependency installation Copying instead. Exception: [WinError 1314] Le client ne dispose pas d’un privilège nécessaire: 'C:\\Users\\numer\\S4\\ML Ops\\mlruns\\280660009522813491\\09e1ab82c96d4e3599342218aa1bd0bd\\artifacts\\sklearn-model\\conda.yaml' -> 'C:\\Users\\numer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpsr7hg68i\\conda.yaml'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [20 lines of output]
  C:\Users\numer\.mlflow\envs\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:27: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
    warnings.warn(
  WARNING setuptools_scm.pyproject_reading toml section missing 'pyproject.toml does not contain a tool.setuptools_scm section'
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4
  copying lz4\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4
  copying lz4\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4\block
  copying lz4\block\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4\block
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4\frame
  copying lz4\frame\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4\frame
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4\stream
  copying lz4\stream\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\lz4\stream
  running build_ext
  building 'lz4._version' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for lz4
ERROR: Could not build wheels for lz4, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
2024/01/19 17:15:54 WARNING mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Encountered an unexpected error: ShellCommandException("Non-zero exit code: 1\nCommand: ['cmd', '/c', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\numer\\\\.mlflow\\\\envs\\\\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79\\\\Scripts\\\\activate.bat & python -m pip install --quiet -r requirements.ad36f2550a7941e1b9d9d42e4d66e1e2.txt']") while creating a virtualenv environment in C:\Users\numer\.mlflow\envs\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79, removing the environment directory...
2024/01/19 17:15:55 WARNING mlflow.utils.virtualenv: Encountered unexpected error while creating C:\Users\numer\.mlflow\envs\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\Scripts\mlflow.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\models\cli.py", line 102, in serve
    return get_flavor_backend(
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\pyfunc\backend.py", line 234, in serve
    return self.prepare_env(local_path).execute(
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\pyfunc\backend.py", line 112, in prepare_env
    activate_cmd = _get_or_create_virtualenv(
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\virtualenv.py", line 364, in _get_or_create_virtualenv
    return _create_virtualenv(
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\virtualenv.py", line 283, in _create_virtualenv
    _exec_cmd(cmd, capture_output=capture_output, cwd=tmpdir, extra_env=extra_env)
  File "C:\Users\numer\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mlflow\utils\process.py", line 117, in _exec_cmd
    raise ShellCommandException.from_completed_process(comp_process)
mlflow.utils.process.ShellCommandException: Non-zero exit code: 1
Command: ['cmd', '/c', 'C:\\Users\\numer\\.mlflow\\envs\\mlflow-afd6d95b329fa275f6dc624cef5c5dba88bf7e79\\Scripts\\activate.bat & python -m pip install --quiet -r requirements.ad36f2550a7941e1b9d9d42e4d66e1e2.txt']
```

I tried to install wheel and Cmake with pip and to change permissions for files but I still had the problem...
Please, help me...
Thank you in advance for your answers !